# Listas que cambian de valor cuando lo hacen otras

Tags: python, lista, spyder

Llevo unos meses programando con python 3.9 y me estoy encontrando con una situación en que una lista que no quiero tocar (b), se modifica cuando modifico otra (c) que he creado a partir de la primera. Por si alguien me podría explicar qué es lo que no veo o estoy haciendo mal.

Mi código es muy sencillo y cambia los elementos de **c** que coincidan en valor y posición con los de **a**:

```
a = [4,5,6]
b = [45,5,36]
c = b
i = 0
for number in c:
    if a[i] == number:
        c[i]=0
    i=i+1
print('a =', a)
print('b =', b)
print('c =', c)
```

Lo que esperaría sería obtener el resultado:

```
a = [4,5,6]
b = [45,5,36]
c = [45,0,36]
```

Y sin embargo, obtengo este otro:

```
a = [4,5,6]
b = [45,0,36]
c = [45,0,36]
```

en el que el segundo elemento de **b** también se modifica. No entiendo porqué puede estar pasando esto. ¿Acaso la asignación `c = b` hace que todo lo que le pase a **c** durante la ejecución se refleje en **b** también? ¿Es porque son listas?

Gracias!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sí, es porque son listas. Cuando escribe `c=b`, python asigna el nombre `c` a la lista nombrada `b`. Las variables `b` y `c` ahora refieren a la misma lista y son sinónimos.

Si quiere copiar la lista `b` y asignar el nombre `c` a la copia, escriba `c=b.copy()` o `c=b[:]`. Así, la lista `b` no cambia cuando modifica la lista `c`.

Comment: Entiendo, si! Muchas gracias, que no lo sabía :) ahora sí que funciona.