# Problema diccionario de diccionario de python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Estoy tratando de asignar valores en un diccionario de diccionarios, deberian de asignarse valores de cantidades en uno de los subdiccionarios y alimentos en el otro, en las variables que se estan asignando hay respectivamente valores y alimentos:

````
keys_diasemana=["0", "1",'2','3','4','5','6']
       dic_menu, diccionario_menu_cantidades,diccionario_menu_alimentos= {}, {},{}      
       for i in range(len(keys_diasemana)):
            valor = [[], [], [], []]
            diccionario_menu_cantidades[str(i)] = valor
            diccionario_menu_alimentos[str(i)] = valor
       dic_menu["cantidades"] = diccionario_menu_cantidades
       dic_menu["alimentos"] = diccionario_menu_alimentos

       for dia in keys_diasemana:
           for i,k in enumerate ([-1,6,13,18]):
               for j in range (self.dict[dia][1][i].size()):
                    k+=1
                    dic_menu["cantidades"][dia][i].append(self.dict[dia][0][k].get())
                    dic_menu["alimentos"][dia][i].append(self.dict[dia][1][i].get(j))```
````

Cuando reviso dic_menu tanto el key cantidades como alimentos tienen los mismos valores insertados cuando deberian estar separados, existe algun problema con la asignacion?

Comment: Los valores de `diccionario_menu_cantidades` y `diccionario_menu_alimentos` son el mismo objeto: `valor`, por tanto al modificar el valor en un diccionario (como son el mismo) lo verás también modificado en el otro.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Python al hacer append de un segundo objeto me modifica la lista de el primer objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/552680/python-al-hacer-append-de-un-segundo-objeto-me-modifica-la-lista-de-el-primer-ob)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Listas que cambian de valor cuando lo hacen otras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/462063)

Comment: Como comenta Jorge a ambos diccionarios le estas asignando el mismo objeto para cada clave (la lista asociada a la variable `valor`). Lo mas simple en tu caso es asignar a cada una un objeto nuevo:     `diccionario_menu_cantidades[str(i)] = [[], [], [], []]`  y
    `diccionario_menu_alimentos[str(i)] = [[], [], [], []]`.  Las asignaciones en Python no crean copias del objeto, simplemente crean nuevos enlaces/referencias al objeto.